# Executing controller's method from another controller - on save -> refresh corresponding table

Tags: java, javafx

Departments controllers are loaded from `SceneWithButtonsController`. `StageAddController` is loaded from `LayoutWithHomeAndAddController`. I want to execute this method from `StageAddController` which executes corresponding method from departments controller :

//Show Stage to add a worker

```
public class LayoutWithHomeAndAddController {
    @FXML
    private void addButtonClicked() throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/views/StageAdd.fxml"));
        BorderPane addWorkerPane = loader.load();

        StageAddController stageAddController = loader.getController();


        Stage stageAdd = new Stage();
        stageAdd.setTitle("Add New Worker");
        stageAdd.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
        Scene scene = new Scene(addWorkerPane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/css/redBorder.css");
        stageAdd.setScene(scene);
        stageAdd.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        Stage mainStage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
        stageAdd.initOwner(mainStage);
        stageAdd.show();}
}
```

Controller class where departments are loaded:

```
public class SceneWithButtonsController {


//Show workers from Mechanical Department
   @FXML
    private void mechanicalDepartmentButtonClicked() throws IOException {
       FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
       loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/views/MechanicalDepartment.fxml"));
       BorderPane mehOdjel = loader.load();
       MechanicalDepartmentController mechanicalDepartmentController = loader.getController();
       mechanicalDepartmentController.populateTable();
       BorderPane borderPane = (BorderPane) pane.getParent();
       borderPane.setCenter(mehOdjel);

    }

    //Show workers from Electrical Department
    @FXML
    private  void electricalDepartmentButtonClicked() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/views/ElectricalDepartment.fxml"));
        BorderPane elOdjel = loader.load();
        ElectricalDepartmentController electricalDepartmentController = loader.getController();
        electricalDepartmentController.populateTable();
        BorderPane borderPane = (BorderPane) pane.getParent();
        borderPane.setCenter(elOdjel);

    }
}
```

StageAddController:

```
public class StageAddController {

private ElectricalDepartmentController electricalDepartmentController;
    private MechanicalDepartmentController mechanicalDepartmentController;

    public void setElectricalDepartmentController(ElectricalDepartmentController electricalDepartmentController) {
        this.electricalDepartmentController = electricalDepartmentController;
    }

    public void setMechanicalDepartmentController(MechanicalDepartmentController mechanicalDepartmentController) {
        this.mechanicalDepartmentController = mechanicalDepartmentController;
    }


public void refreshTableOnSaveButtonClicked() {
    if (departmentBox.getValue().equals("Electrical")) {        
        electricalDepartmentController.refreshButtonClicked();
    }
    else if(departmentBox.getValue().equals("Mechanical")) {
        mechanicalDepartmentController.refreshButtonClicked();
    }
}
}
```

This means that `refreshButtonClicked()` method  from `ElectricalDepartmentController` or `MechanicalDepartmentController` will be executed.

ElectricalDepartmentController (same is with MechanicalDepartmentController):

```
public class ElectricalDepartmentController {

public void initialize() throws IOException {
        StageAddController stageAddController = new StageAddController();
        stageAddController.setElectricalDepartmentController(this);
        workersTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nameSurname"));
        rowSelected();
    }
 @FXML
    public void populateTable() {
        for(Worker worker : workerDao.getWorkersNameSurname("Electrical")) workersList.addAll(worker);
        workersTable.setItems(workersList);
    }

@FXML
    public void refreshButtonClicked() {
        workersList.removeAll(workersList);
        populateTable();
    }
}
```

How to achieve this.

Comment: Wrong design. Use some service class and put refreshButtonClicked() there.

Comment: I do have method in service class which contains logic and is used in  `refreshButtonClicked()` method to connect with corresponding table and button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link controllers. In order to do that, when loading the respective FXML for the subordinate form, you have to set the parent controller for it manually so that you can have access to it.

Unfortunately, FXML does not provide a native way to link controllers. What you want to do is you want to use the full `FXMLLoader` functionality (instead of using `FXMLLoader.load()`), since the `FXMLLoader` also has a `getController()` method. It's probably a wise idea for your controllers to implement something like this:

```
public interface HierarchicalController {
    HierarchicalController getParentController();
    void setParentController(HierarchicalController controller);
}
```

EDIT: Component preload code:

```
public class SceneWithButtonsController {

   protected FXMLLoader<?> mechanicalLoader;
   protected FXMLLoader<?> electricalLoader;
   protected BorderPane mechanicalPane;
   protected BorderPane electricalPane;

   public void initialize() {
       mechanicalLoader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/views/MechanicalDepartment.fxml"));
       mechanicalPane = loader.load();
       MechanicalDepartmentController mechanicalDepartmentController = loader.getController();
       mechanicalDepartmentController.populateTable();

       electricalLoader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/views/MechanicalDepartment.fxml"));
       electricalPane = loader.load();
       ElectricalDepartmentController electricalDepartmentController = loader.getController();
       electricalDepartmentController.populateTable();

       // now what is the relation between StageAddController and SceneWithButtonsController ?

   }

   //Show workers from Mechanical Department
   @FXML
    private void mechanicalDepartmentButtonClicked() throws IOException {
       BorderPane borderPane = (BorderPane) pane.getParent();
       borderPane.setCenter(mechanicalPane);

    }

    //Show workers from Electrical Department
    @FXML
    private  void electricalDepartmentButtonClicked() throws IOException {
        BorderPane borderPane = (BorderPane) pane.getParent();
        borderPane.setCenter(electricalPane);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show that in an example. I tried lot of stuff with  `loader.getController` but it gives me an exeption on calling the `refreshButtonClicked()` method.

Comment: Sure, as a matter of fact, just did a sample of that with my students yesterday :) see https://github.com/pwilkin/ppa1/blob/plansze/src/sample/Plansze.java and https://github.com/pwilkin/ppa1/blob/plansze/src/sample/Plansza1.java

Comment: Can I use initialize method, can you please take a look at updated question?

Comment: No, you can't. 

The reason for this is that FXML creates its controller by reflection. The controller that you manually create by using `new StageAddController();` is not the same controller object that the one created by `FXMLLoader`. If you want to pass something to **the** controller (i.e. the one actually associated with the loaded form), you have to use `loader.getController()` at load time.

Comment: StageAdd and Departments are loaded in the different classes. When loading StageAdd I need to have access to departments loaders to get theirs controllers. How to achieve that

Comment: Without seeing the architecture of your forms (the .fxml files) it's hard to tell. You can't access loaders in advance, you can only do that at the very moment at which you actually add the subordinate .fxml generated component to your layout. I'd have to see the code that actually adds the layout elements. 

If you're not adding an element dynamically and you just want a separate controller for your embedded element, that you might want to use the `<fx:include>` directive, as per https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers

Comment: Oh, and if you do use `<fx:include>`, then indeed you can link the controllers in `initialize()`.

Comment: Okay, so this: `stageAddController.setElectricalDepartmentController(this);` should go into `LayoutWithHomeAndAddController::addButtonClicked()` (after `loader.load()`) instead of where it is now.

Comment: This class is not ElectricalDepartmentController, see setElectricalDepartmentController() method...

Comment: Ah, I see. Then it looks like a case of you having to preload the two components in advance in the `initiialize()` method of the `StageAddController`, keep the respective loaders as fields in the `StageAddController` and mutually initialize the subcontrollers.

Comment: This kind of design is going to get pretty complex, and consequently hard to understand and maintain. Instead of all the controllers having references to each other, consider using a model class and sharing an instance of it with each controller. If you implement the table contents using `ObservableList`s and keep those lists in the model, the appropriate controllers can just observe the lists and table updates should be essentially transparent. You can also consider using a dependency injection framework to make it easier to share the model instance with the controllers.

Comment: Added together with question.

Comment: @James_D any sort of synchronization is generally hard to understand and maintain. Especially dependency injection introduces a lot of logical overhead. A domain-driven architecture is nice, but not always feasible, since not all synchronization actions between controllers are data-driven. 

When the infrastructure becomes really cumbersome, the usual solution is to provide some sort of central instance that manages it all - be it a domain model, an event bus or a service locator. What it should be really depends on the application in question.

Comment: @PiotrWilkin Understood, but in this case all that is happening is that the synchronization (apparently) needs to happen because the contents of one of more lists change. JavaFX is designed for this to happen automatically, as long as you share and modify the `ObservableList`s. So I think the "shared object" is pretty clear in this case, no?

Comment: @James_D Can you please show example with model class?

Comment: @Kvark900 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx/32343342#32343342